# Why do some variables get substituted and others don't?

Tags: function-construction, scoping, variable

I was running into some trouble with my math and I whittled it down to this nugget:

```
fred := a*b;
bob[a_, b_] := fred;
joe[a_] := Sum[bob[a, b], {b, Range[3]}];
bob[1, 2]
joe[2]
```

Which evaluates to:

```
a b
6 a
```

So why is the Sum[] function able to reach through bob into fred but the input parameters to the function can't?

I'm still new to Mathematica, so please forgive me if this question is a duplicate, I wasn't able to find an answer but maybe I don't know the right search terms to use.

P.S. I note that the following code:

```
dan[a_, b_] := a*b;
sue[a_] := Sum[dan[a, b], {b, Range[3]}];
sue[2]
```

Correctly yields 12 as I would expect.

Comment: Change to `bob[a_, b_] = fred` instead of `:=`.

Comment: ... or define `bob` as `bob[a_, b_] := Evaluate @ fred;`

Comment: To get a better idea of how the `b`'s are scoped, do `joe[2] // Trace`.

Answer (score 1):

Tis needs an explanation. Consider:

```
fred := a*b;
bob[a_, b_] := fred;
joe[a_] := 
  Sum[Print[{"a=", a, "b=", b, "bob=", HoldForm[bob[a, b]], bob[a, b],
      "fred=", fred}]; bob[a, b], {b, Range[3]}];
joe[2]
```

{a=,2,b=,1,bob=,bob[2,b],a,fred=,a}

{a=,2,b=,2,bob=,bob[2,b],2 a,fred=,2 a}

{a=,2,b=,3,bob=,bob[2,b],3 a,fred=,3 a}

As soon as joe is called, the argument "a" is replaced by "2"  everywhere in joes code

```
joe[a_] := Sum[ bob[a, b], {b, Range[3]}];
Sum[ bob[2, b], {b, Range[3]}]
```

Note that fred is not touched. Then Sum is evaluated:

```
bob[a,1]+bob[a,2]+bob[a,3]
```

Finally bob is evaluated:

```
a+2a+3a
```